# Leaflet draw layers disappearing after creation in Django

Tags: leaflet, geodjango, leaflet-draw, django

I implemented leaflet in my Django project, and managed to add the draw functionalities. The thing is after i draw the shape instantly disappears. What should i do to solve the problem?

map.html

```
{% load static %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  {% leaflet_css plugins="ALL" %}
  <title>Map</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'map.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
     href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  {% leaflet_js plugins="ALL" %}
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="{% static 'map.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

map.js

```
var mapcenter = [41.47132109359731, 12.907624901567564];
var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false}).setView(mapcenter, 11);

var osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '1652310'}).addTo(map);

// Zoom Control
var zoomControl = L.control.zoom({
  position: "topleft"
});
zoomControl.addTo(map);

var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems,
        polygon: {
            allowIntersection: false
        }
    },
    draw: {
        circle: false,
        circlemarker: false,
        polygon: {
            allowIntersection: false
        }
    }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you finish drawing of feature/geometry, item is not automatically added to the feature layer, you have to add it through `L.Draw.Event.CREATED` event processing function:

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (event) {
  var layer = event.layer;
  drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});
```

Comment: thanks :) don't know why the .layer is deprecated but it works :)